# Why does `for _ in 1,1` iterate twice?

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

I had this piece of code (paraphrased for simplicity) somewhere that seemed to work fine:

```
for _ in 1, x:
  do_something()
```

As you would guess, it should do_something x times. If x is 2, do_something happens twice as expected. But one day x equalled 1. Why does python treat the range `1,1` as having two elements?

```
>>> for x in 1,2:
...   print(x)
...
1
2
>>> for x in 1,1:
...   print(x)
...
1
1
```

Is there an alternative I should use to really do something x times? ComputerCraftEdu defined the repeat construct which I think more programming languages should implement; it just takes a number and then a block of code to execute that many times. How would one do that in python?

Comment: `1, x` isn't a range. It's two objects: `1` and `x`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`1,1` is a tuple containing two elements, both their values are 1. Consider for instance:

```
>>> for x in 0, 1, 2, 3, 4:
...   print(x)
...
0
1
2
3
4
```

The confusion likely stems from lua, in which `for x = init,max[,step]` is the syntax for for loops:

```
> for x = 1, 2 do
... print(x)
... end
1
2
> for x = 1, 1 do
... print(x)
... end
1
```

Pylint should probably have warned about this, since the value of x was never used.

The repeat function could be implemented:

```
def repeat(n, f):
  for _ in range(n):
    f()

repeat(1, lambda: print("hi"))
```

Comment: Semantics, but `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` will create a `tuple` not a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need range then you have to follow Zen 2 explicit is better than implicit:

```
for _ in range(x):
  do_something()
```